# DOMPDF, brings me an error

Tags: php, html, mysql, dompdf

This is my code in a PdfHtml class:

```
public function createTable($result){

    $html = "<html>
                    <body>
                        <table>
                            <th>
                                <td>Descripción</td>
                                <td>Artículo</td>
                                <td>Precio</td>
                            </th>
                        ";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td>".$row["producto"]."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$row["idProducto"]."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$row["precio"]."</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";
    }

    $html .= "</table>
                </body>
                    </html>";

    return $html;
}
</i>
```

I'm execute with the following:

```
$pdfHtml = new PdfHTML();
$result = $pdfHtml->getProductosPorMarca($idMarca);
$html = $pdfHtml->createTable($result);

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->output();
```

And throw this:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ONLINE/dompdf0.6/include/table_frame_decorator.cls.php on line 304 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ONLINE/dompdf0.6/include/frame.cls.php on line 726
```

Please help me, i dont found where is my error!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your HTML is the source of the problem. You have nested a bunch of TD elements inside a TH element, but this is not valid. The container should still be a TR element; the individual cells would then be TH elements. And if you want a table header that repeats across pages you nest the header rows in a THEAD element and the body of the table in a TBODY element.

Comment: Ichange the html code for this, and brings me this: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ONLINE/dompdf0.6/include/cellmap.cls.php on line 399. 
Have you an example? thank you

Comment: An updated code sample would be helpful for figuring out what's going on with your code. You may want to also try validating the  HTML generated by your code: http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 0):

basic < table > elements:

```
$html = "<html>
                    <body>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>Artículo</th>
                                <th>Precio</th>
                            </tr>
                        ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes (`' '`), like this:

```
public function createTable($result){
  $html = '<html>
                <body>
                    <table>
                        <th>
                            <td>Descripción</td>
                            <td>Artículo</td>
                            <td>Precio</td>
                        </th>';


  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<td>".$row["producto"]."</td>";
    $html .= "<td>".$row["idProducto"]."</td>";
    $html .= "<td>".$row["precio"]."</td>";
    $html .= "</tr>';
  }

  $html .= '</table>
            </body>
            </html>';

  return $html;
}
```